# Is it possible to use different framework library just for one component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using Vuetify Vue3 for a project. There are some components missing that are available in other fw. Does this cause messup in the project by installing extra fw for one component?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed have several frameworks at the same time, but it may drastically impact your performance and lead to messy code because of the difference in APIs.
If you are meaning, CSS like a UI framework (Vuetify, Bulma, Bootstrap etc...), the answer is the same. Doable but quite heavy.

Nothing stopping you from going crazy by using all of them!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can use at the same time, but if you mean CSS frameworks sometimes it can lead to conflict between classes.
It is not recommended and best practice to do that because it can cause a conflict and also can make your application heavy.
But it is not forbidden and you are free to try.

Comment: Usually, UI frameworks do have namespaces like `v-` or `b-` prefixed in their classes.